# How to create users from list in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I'm trying to create users with the prefix sit from a list of the greek alphabet. Like sit-alpha, sit-beta, so on.

This is what I have so far:

```
BEGIN
  LIST:= 'alpha, beta, gamma';
  FOR u IN LIST

  LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER SIT-' || TO_CHAR (U)||' IDENTIFIED BY
CLERK'||TO_CHAR (U) ;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO SIT-'||TO_CHAR(U);

  END LOOP;

END;
```

But it says "PLS-00201: identifier 'LIST' must be declared". How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly correct. However, you need to split the comma-separated list of values into an array using the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function to loop through each element in the list. About the error "PLS-00201: identifier 'LIST' must be declared" means that the `LIST` variable you used in your code is not declared. This error usually occurs when a variable has not been declared or initialized correctly. In your code, you must declare the `LIST` variable before using it. You can do this by using the `DECLARE` command at the beginning of your code, like this:

```
  DECLARE
      LIST VARCHAR2(200) := 'alpha, beta, gamma';
    BEGIN
      FOR u IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(LIST, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS val FROM dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(LIST, ',') + 1)
    
      LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER SIT-' || u.val || ' IDENTIFIED BY CLERK' || u.val;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO SIT-' || u.val;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Here's a great explanation of my code :

The first line of the code is a `DECLARE` command that indicates the beginning of a variable declaration section. This section declares all the variables and constants that will be used in the rest of the code.

The second line declares a `LIST` variable of type `VARCHAR2` with a maximum length of 200 characters. This variable contains a comma-separated list of the user names you wish to create.

The third line is the `BEGIN` command that indicates the start of the executable code block.

The fourth line begins a `FOR` loop that traverses each item in the list of usernames using a `SELECT` query.

The `SELECT` query uses the `regexp_substr` function to retrieve each comma-separated item in the list and returns it as a `val`. The `trim` function is used to remove any unnecessary spaces that may be present around each element in the list. The `CONNECT BY` clause is used to generate the rows necessary for the `FOR` loop to traverse each element in the list.

The `FOR` loop uses the variable `u` to store each element in the list at each iteration.

The two `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` commands inside the `FOR` loop create a new user using the username SIT- followed by the value of `val`, and then add CONNECT and RESOURCE privileges to that user.

Finally, the last line of code is the `END` command which indicates the end of the executable code block.

In summary, this code extracts each item from the list of user names, creates a new user with a name that includes that item, and then adds CONNECT and RESOURCE privileges to that user. This code uses Oracle functions to extract each item from the list and dynamically create the users.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the explanations.

Comment: Note that the dash "-" is not a legal character for non-quoted usernames or other database object names such as in your `create user` command. Use the underscore "_" instead. Use of quoted identifiers is generally considered bad practice.